# HighCharts Month/multiple data array error

Tags: php, sql-server, json, highcharts

My problem is as follows:

I have a database that gives me two sets of information as shown in the picture below:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ijshg.png

I can't quite figure out if my PHP/JSON or SQL is the problem here..
Im aware that my JSON data-sets should have more than one data, eg:

[{"name":"Person1","data":[123123, etc, etc , etc]}

My problem is that it is showed as:

[{"name":"Person1","data":[123123]}

[{"name":"Person1","data":[2345436]}

JSON (changed names and numbers for privacy issues):

```
[{"name":"Person1","data":[123123]},{"name":"Person1","data":[123123]}
,{"name":"Person2","data":[123123]},{"name":"Person2","data":[123123]}
,{"name":"Person3","data":[123123]},{"name":"Person3","data":[123123]}
,{"name":"Person4","data":[123123]},{"name":"Person4","data":[123123]}]
```

SQL (also changed, should be the same query though):

```
$SQL = "SELECT ISNULL(USERNAME) AS Accountmanagers, xMonth AS xMonth, ROUND(SUM(report.[FATDOLLARS(EUR)]), 0) AS COGS
FROM SecretDB 
WHERE xYear = '2013'
GROUP BY ISNULL(USERNAME), xMonth
ORDER BY ISNULL(USERNAME), xMonth
```

my query looks like this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/BAz7I.png

This is the php i use for my JSON data:

```
while( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $somevariablehere, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC) ) 
{

    $name = $row['Accountmanagers'];

    $categories = array($row['xMonth']);

    $data = array($row['COGS']);

    $arr[] = array('name' => $name, 'data' => $data);  
}

$arr = json_encode($arr, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);

echo $arr;
```

HighChart ("series: json" is replaced with dummy data):

```
<script>
$(function () {
    var chart3;
    $(document).ready(function() {

       // $.getJSON("account.php", function(json) {

            chart3 = new Highcharts.Chart({
                chart: {
                    renderTo: 'accountmanagers',
                    type: 'column'
                },
                title: {
                    text: '2012'
                },
                xAxis: {
                    categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Okt', 'Nov', 'Dec'],
                    title: { text: 'Month'}
                },
                yAxis: {
                    min: 0,
                    title: {
                        text: 'Revenue'
                    }
                },
                legend: {
                    layout: 'vertical',
                    backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF',
                    align: 'left',
                    verticalAlign: 'top',
                    x: 100,
                    y: 70,
                    floating: true,
                    shadow: true
                },
                tooltip: {
                    formatter: function() {
                         return '<b>'+ this.series.name +'</b><br/>'+
                            this.x +': '+ this.y +'€';
                    }
                },
                plotOptions: {
                    column: {
                        pointPadding: 0.2,
                        borderWidth: 0
                    }
                },
                    series: [{"name":"Person1","data":[12528]},{"name":"Person1","data":[2658]},{"name":"Person2","data":[27368]},{"name":"Person2","data":[30793]},{"name":"Person3","data":[64987]},{"name":"Person3","data":[21582]},{"name":"Person4","data":[53735]},{"name":"Person4","data":[14810]}]
            });
       // });
    });

});
        </script>
```

I don't know if you need any more information, if so, please let me know.

I want to combine the "Person" or Accountmanager values and of course spread them over the months, instead of creating new series for each data.

Thanks in advance :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the error - it was the SQL query, i made a whole bunch of left outer joins, which (after many copy/paste's) gave me data for each month with one series.name to it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide values for each user for all the months that you have mentioned in the categories.
You are passing 2 values for each person that to separately that is why you  are getting graph for only JAN

Ex

```
series: [{
            name: 'Person1',
            data: [49.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]

        }, {
            name: 'Person2',
            data: [83.6, 78.8, 98.5, 93.4, 106.0, 84.5, 105.0, 104.3, 91.2, 83.5, 106.6, 92.3]

        }]
```

Sample [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/column-basic/) provided by high charts

Comment: Yes i'm aware of that, each person should have multiple sets of data, eg.

[{"name":"Person1","data":[123123, 34567, etc, etc,]}]

My problem is that i get the data out the other way, how can i fix this?

Comment: Your query looks fine. The prob is in the php where you are creating, you are receiving separate rows for each month's data you need to create separate array of data for each user which has its data for each month.

Comment: That sounds about right. How can i do this? I'm not that pro with php yet :-) i don't know if it's clear or not, but the table xMonth is just numbers 1 to 12